# Why were the Katayanagi Twins not as fleshed out as the other Exes in Scott Pilgrim?

Tags: plot-explanation, book-adaptation, scott-pilgrim-vs.-the-world

Mathew Patel, Lucas Lee, Todd Ingram, Roxie Richter, and (obviously) Gideon Graves were all fleshed out rather decently by having their own epic fight scene as well as back-story from Romona in the movie.  However, the Twins seemed to be a thrown in scene with a lot of special effects and nothing else really memorable other than shiny lights and a few giant monsters.

[image: holographic ape vs a holographic two-headed eastern dragon]

Does anyone know the reason why the creation of their characters went this way instead of seeing an epic 2v1 fight of a pissed-off Pilgrim vs 2 Japanese twins?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Off the wiki](http://scottpilgrim.wikia.com/wiki/Kyle_%26_Ken_Katayanagi#In_vs._the_World) it says:

> Unlike the book, where they are devious, plan extensively, and speak at great length; the movie shows them as silent attackers in one scene only. This is due to multiple factors. The length of the movie was one, finding gorgeous Japanese identical twins who spoke English was another; The Saitos couldn't speak English.

To reiterate: **The actors could *not* speak English**! Hence they did not have a speaking part in the movie.

Comment: Still seems kind of lazy from a movie with such detail.  Won't prevent me from loving it any less than I do however.

Comment: @Shads0 that is true ^_^